# Set of integers with topology

Tags: general-topology

let $\{ , \dots \{-1, 0, 1\}, \{1\}, \{1,2,3\}, \{3\} \dots \}$ be an open cover of $\mathbb{Z}$. (*Is there any other open cover ?*)

Now,If we drop any of the even number containing subsets then we can conclude that the space is not compact but I am not able to provide a better argument for the odd numbers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to ask here?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create another open cover by simply including it with union of open sets, such as $\{1,3\}$ (so the open cover is $\{\dots,\{-1,0,1\},\{1\},\{1,2,3\},\{3\},\dots\} \cup \{1,3\}$), and you can do it with any other open set that is not a basis element.
2. $\mathbb{Z}$ is not compact under this topology. Suppose it is compact, then the open cover you prescribed has a finite subcover, say $S \subseteq \{\dots,\{-1,0,1\},\{1\},\{1,2,3\},\{3\},\dots\}$. Since each set in this cover is of the form $\{n - 1,n,n+1\}$ for even $n$ and $\{n\}$ for odd $n$, I can write it as follows:
   $$
   S = \{\{n_1 - 1, n_1, n_1 + 1\}, \{n_2 - 1, n_2, n_2 + 1\}, \dots, \{n_k - 1, n_k, n_k + 1\}\} \cup \{\{n_1'\},\{n_2'\},\dots,\{n_l'\}\}
   $$
   where $n_1,\dots,n_k$ are even numbers, and $n_1',\dots,n_l'$ are odd numbers. Let $n_i$ and $n_j'$ be the smallest even and odd numbers in this set respectively, and let $N = \min\{n_i - 1,n_j'\}$. Then $N - 1$ does not belong to any set in $S$, contradicting that it's an open cover. Thus, the original set cannot have any finite subcover.

More generally, given a topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$, if $X$ is infinite and $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in \mathcal{I}}$ is an open cover such that each of $U_\alpha$ is finite, then $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in \mathcal{I}}$ can't have a finite subcover (say $\{U_i\}_{i=1}^n$), as that would imply $X \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n U_i$ is also finite.

Comment: @cabmetric Edited. Please take a look.

Comment: @cabmetric you're right, but the argument is the same.